# Regex extract numbers from Url (except port number)

Tags: c#, regex

i have to extract id value of a product from url.

It is SEO Friendly (url routing).

Url can be

```
http://www.example.com/{param0}/{param1}/123/{param2}/{paramN}
```

Or

```
http://localhost:6847/{param0}/{param1}/123/{param2}/{paramN}
```

For the first url there is no problem.
But for the second i want to extract ONLY the 123 or (ID) <-(It is an Integer).

I know that if i want to extract only numbers i can use

```
[0-9]+
```

but how can i tell regengine how to get all the numerical data from url except numbers that may have

```
:
```

before.
i use :

```
((!:)[0-9]+)
```

it is not correct.
Every advice is wellcamed:)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be more info on what delimits the `123` in your example.

On its face, `(?<!:)[0-9]+` will find the first clump of digits NOT preceded by ':'

**Edit** Probably for more accuracy, this `(?<!:\d+)[0-9]+` would be better.
Note this is if .NET allows variable length look-behind (I think it does).

For fixed length look-behind (PCRE), something like this might work: `(?<![:\d])[0-9]+`

**Edit2**

@Sanosay- After thinking about .NET type lookbehinds, the above regex needs a slight change.
It should be `(?<!:\d*)[0-9]+` . Thats because in '**:**`1234`', `1` will satisfy the assertion.

Hope you figured this to be the case. I made a test case for the two regex's
`@"(?<!:\d*)[0-9]+"`
`@"(?<![:\d])[0-9]+"`
that satisfy the conditions.

The link to the ideone C# code is here: http://ideone.com/tLn2j

Comment: The 123 is for example an ID of a product (only int).
I will test your solution..i think that it will work:)

Comment: :/ It is not working.
(i think i have test that solution before).
Ouput for http://localhost:14964/rToz/product/311/Testing :  4964